# robot.keyPress won't work properly in java for game trainer

Tags: java

I want to create a game trainer for mount and blade, the game itself have cheat features in it and I want to take advantage of it.

For example when you want increase your money you should press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> but it's boring.

So I create a code that if you press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> 100 times for me but it's just working once and not 100 times.

```
try {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.delay(5000);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

    for(int y = 0; y < 100; y++)
    {
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_X);
    }
} catch (AWTException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note:

1. If I put

   ```
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL)
   ```

   in the for loop, the code won’t work
2. If I put any robot.keyRelease in code it stops working

Why is it just working one time?

Comment: Link to the Robot class code ? Seems like only one event is dispatched per frame

Comment: add short sleep period. probably the game does only take X actions per second and you exceed them too fast

Comment: you forget the *keyRelease*

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#keyPress(int)), if you press a key, it will be pressed until you released it. So if you press `Ctrl + X` and then you press X in the loop you will be getting this `Ctrl + X + X ...`

```
try {
    Robot robot = new Robot();           
    robot.delay(5000);
    for(int y=0;y < 100 ; y++)
    {
      robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
      robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_X);   

      robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);   
      robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_X);  
    }
    } catch (AWTException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

EDIT:

Also, as XtremeBaumer said in the comments, probably the game could detect you are cheating if you "press" the keys so fast. Adding some delay between each iteration would make it worked.